# many to many relation list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two list having many to many relationship. i know how to handle one to many reltionshiip with list ; lookup field.

Can any body give me idea how to handle many to many reltionship with list in sharepoint 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Add a 3rd list? I don't understand why this would be different than modeling a many-to-many relationship in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices.

You can use a 3rd list.  The list will have lookups to the first two lists and describes the relationships, possibly with any information about the relationship itself.

You can use a multi-valued lookup.

Both have their own advantages and disadvantages.  We would need to know more about how each are used and what is most important in order to determine which suits your needs better.